# SKAction.playSoundFileNamed() Causes Crash at High Memory

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, avaudioplayer, skaction

I want to play multiple sounds at once. I use `SpriteKit` `SKAction` like this ：

```
SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("aa.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
```

I found that the application crashes when the memory usage increases.

- I tried `SKAudioNode`, but doesn't provide a very good performance.
- I tried `AVAudioPlayer`, but I don't know how to play multiple sounds at one
  time by `AVAudioPlayer`.

Below is the error:

---

Code：

```
  static func palyBulletAttackedSound(node:SKNode)
    {
        if(isSound)
        {

            let bulletSoundAction =   SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("LichMissileHit2.wav", waitForCompletion: true)
            if(node.actionForKey("sound")==nil)
            {
                node.runAction(bulletSoundAction, withKey: "sound")                            }
          }
    }
```

update：

```
 let bulletSoundAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("LichMissileHit2.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
    func bulletUpdate(currentTime:CFTimeInterval)
    {
         ……
         //SoundUtil.palyBulletAttackedSound(map)
         map.runAction(bulletSoundAction)

    }
```

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/26855048/4078517

Comment: Have some questions. Why static? what is `isSound`? Why you are checking for `if(node.actionForKey("sound")==nil)`? Instead of all this function i would recommend to just play your sound on (contact if i understand correctly from your code) like this: `self.runAction.SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("LichMissileHit2.wav", waitForCompletion: false)`

Comment: thanks,i have a try.

Comment: i add code，please look at it.

Answer (score 0):

To play multiple sounds at one time use `waitForCompletion: false` instead of `waitForCompletion: true`.

In `Scene` do Like this:

```
self.runAction.SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("aa.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
```

Comment: @LeiLiu Are your writting like this ?     self.runAction.SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("aa.wav", waitForCompletion: false)

Comment: @LeiLiu How you know that memory increase cause crash ? Are your sound file name correct?

Comment: i use iPhone connect Xcode debug , i can see  A little bit of increase ,when the memory add to 500m,the crash,file name right

Comment: @LeiLiu i would recommend you to add more code and any information about error.

Answer (score 0):

You know you can run actions in parallel right?

```
let action1 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(one.mp3, waitForCompletion: false)
let action2 = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed(two.mp3, waitForCompletion: false)
node.runAction(SKAction.group([action1, action2])
```